# What is the proper way to catch any non registered routes in Laravel 5.5.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I see that laravel has a `Routes::any()` method, and I am curious as to how to create a route "catcher" that will catch any routes that are not registered and return a 404 page, I know it would be something like `Route:any('/', function() { abort(404) });` accept I don't think it would be `/` as I have that registered as a home page.

All the examples I see are 2 years old and out dated at the time of 5.5 release.

Comment: Can you explain what your end goal is? Why do you want to catch 404 requests?

Comment: Laravel will already issue a 404 for undefined routes.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is customize the view for a 404 page, then there is no need to "catch" anything. [You can just modify the 404 error page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#custom-http-error-pages) in `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`.

If you want to do something when a 404 occurs then you can do it in your [exception handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#the-exception-handler), using the `render` method.

You can also use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) to handle 404s:

```
class ExampleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if($response->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            // Handle 404
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your use-case, [terminable middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#terminable-middleware) may be more appropriate.

Comment: Why not use the `ExceptionHandler` to catch the exceptions and override the response?

Comment: @fubar You can. That's in my answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: no you're not missing something. I just apparently cannot read properly. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

- In Laravel 5.5 there is fallback url, it will be called when no route found for.

  Route::any("{fallback}",function(){

  dd('This is fallback function.');

  });
- OR you can try this for older version like 5.4, 5.3 etc

  Route::any("{all}",function(){

  ```
  dd('This is fallback function');
  ```

  });

Comment: That's incorrect, it should be `Route::fallback` not `Route::any`.

Comment: what was wrong with my answer, not working @mtinsley?